# Excel Chart Referencing Cell With Formula

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, cells

I have a chart (a chart page, not an embedded chart) that I have a title for in Excel 2010. I want to reference a cell so that title changes based on that cell's value. Let's say that the cell is A1. I seen forums saying you can link a chart's title to a cell by clicking it, pressing "=" and clicking on the referenced cell. This works just fine until I want to make put a formula in the title.

Say A1 = "Time", and I set the chart title to `=Sheet1!A1`. The title updates to: **Time**. But if I want to make it more flexible, like `="It's about "&Sheet1!A1`, I get an error:

*The formula you typed contains an error. Try one of the following: ... [clipped]*

Is the title field limited as to its input? Is there another way to accomplish this without VBA?

Comment: According to [this MrExcel article](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/704848-why-doesnt-concatenate-work-graph-title.html), you can only reference a cell in the title text box. It's far from an "official" documentation, but I couldn't find anything more authoritative.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Your suggestion worked. While not ideal, there's no rule against workarounds as answers. Please write up an official answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @tralston answer added as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the Title field can accept only a simple cell reference.

(also tried creating a named range with the required formula, without success)

An alternative is to create another cell with the required formula, and refer to *that* cell for the chart title.

Comment: @tralston This is indeed the correct answer, after going through your question again, what you describe is the opposite of what I'm doing which is what cris provided as answer. I deleted all previous comments to avoid confusions. My bad. Btw, I don't see why doing the formula in a cell is not ideal.

Comment: @L42 In some cases (like for work) I like to keep my spreadsheets as neat and nice looking as possible. When others will see it, it's preferable to not cause confusion by extraneous cells that don't have an apparent purpose. In the past I have colored text white to "hide it" from plain view, but when I have time to give TLC to my worksheet, I like to self-contain as much as possible.